# Issue with repairing 3GP video using untrunc - Error: bad track: 's263'

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, codec, 3gp

I am trying to repair a corrupted 3GP video using the untrunc program, but I'm facing an issue due to an error.

The command I ran:

```
./untrunc -v ~/Desktop/logic/Video0086.3gp ~/Desktop/logic/Video0035.3gp
```

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and using the 'v308-d72ec32' version of the untrunc. The error message I encounter is as follows:

```
Info: version 'v308-d72ec32' using ffmpeg '4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1'
Info: reading /home/hsrv/Desktop/logic/Video0086.3gp
Info: parsing healthy moov atom ... 
ftyp_ = 'mp42'
[amrnb @ 0x56075d7656c0] Multiple frames in a packet.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/hsrv/Desktop/logic/Video0086.3gp':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2014-04-26T21:38:29.000000Z
    com.android.version: 12
  Duration: 00:02:22.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 154 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h263 (s263 / 0x33363273), yuv420p, 176x144 [SAR 12:11 DAR 4:3], 140 kb/s, 10.74 fps, 11 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-07-02T15:34:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: amr_nb (samr / 0x726D6173), 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 12 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-07-02T15:34:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
ss: s263 is_stable: 0
ss: using f=7 span
assuming constant duration of 640 for 'samr' (x1785)

Info: unknown track 's263' found -> fallback to dynamic stats
created dummy track 'free'
removed dummy track 'free'
first_failed: 0 of 101
simpleOrder: 0 
order ( 101): (0, 14) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 10) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 10) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 10) (0, 12) (0, 11) (0, 11) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) (0, 12) 
isTrackOrderEnough: 0  (sz=0)
genPatternPerm of: s263
0 s263 0.918296 3
1 samr 1 2
genPatternPerm of: samr
0 s263 4.8125 32
1 samr 0 1
has_zero_transitions_: 0
**Error: bad track: 's263'**
```

This error message indicates that the untrunc program is having trouble with a track named 's263'. This track could be a track or codec within the video file.

How can I resolve this error and successfully repair the corrupted 3GP video? What steps should I follow or can you suggest an alternative approach?

Thank you in advance!

I was expecting trunc tool to fix the corrupted/trunced video. But it gave me this error and no matter how much I searched for a solution, I couldn't find anything.